# MongoDB Limit number of elements in set after update using C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a use case where I need to insert elements to a set where the amount of items in the set is limited.

I've found this article that desbribes how to do it using `$push` https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/limit-number-of-elements-in-updated-array/

However, I'd like to do the same thing with `$addToSet` using the C# driver. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the Builder AddToSet Method
[Update.AddToSet](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_Update_AddToSet.htm)

which could be used like

```
var updateBuilder = Builders<T>.Update.AddToSet(field, value);
collection.UpdateMany(filterDefiniton, updateBuilder);
```

Comment: I was thinking of using `AddToSet` but as I described in my question, the number of elements in my set is limited. So I also need a way to enforce that limit when doing the update.